# Can unipennate and unicipital be used interchangeably?

Tags: hand

I'm currently revising the intrinsic muscles of the hand and according to my notes, the palmar interossei are unipennate and the dorsal interossei are bipennate. The lumbricals of the index and middle fingers are unicipital, whilst the lumbricals of the ring and little fingers are bicipital. I was wondering if unipennate and unicipital can be used synonymously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope -- unipennate refers to the way in which the muscle fibers spread out from the head(s), while unicipital refers to the number of heads (aka origns).

All the best with your studies!